# Can Lua patterns represent any regular language?

Tags: lua, regular-language, formal-languages

This question does not ask if Lua patterns are PCRE. That has been asked multiple times and the answer is definitely no.

Instead, I am asking if Lua patterns have an analogy to regular languages by the formal language definition. My instinct is no because I was not able to create a pattern for this regular language:

```
L = {'foo'}* = {'', 'foo', 'foofoo', 'foofoofoo', ...}
```

All my attempts failed because Lua appears to lack the ability to use the Kleene Star on captures:

```
> print(('foofoo'):find('(foo)*'))
nil
```

Can you show that there is no pattern in Lua which can denote `L`, and more generally, can a Lua pattern be created for any regular language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua patterns are not regular languages. Almost every Lua pattern can be expressed as a regular language, but there are lots of regular expressions that cannot be expressed as a Lua pattern (and at least one Lua pattern that is not regular). And the particular regular construct you're trying to do, match repetitions of a specific sequence of characters, is not possible with Lua patterns. Not in the general case.

Basically, Lua patterns can't do anything that would require decision points based on more than one character in the input stream. Regular languages can.

Comment: The `%bxy` pattern item is *not* regular: "`%bxy`, where `x` and `y` are two distinct characters; such item matches strings that start with `x`, end with `y`, and where the `x` and `y` are balanced." See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1

Answer (score -1):

Kleene Star can be easily implemented:

```
function belongs_to_L(str)
   return str:gsub("foo", "") == ""
end

print(belongs_to_L("foofoo"))  --> true
print(belongs_to_L("bar"))     --> false
```

Comment: It can be implemented in this specific case. But not in a *general* case within a larger pattern.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Lua can implement anything, including a general case of regular expression.  Guess why?  Because Lua is Turing-complete :-)  Lua patterns is just a feature that makes the task a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, but his question was not "is Lua Turing complete." So that is irrelevant. The question was about the capabilities of Lua patterns relative to regular languages.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Pattern-related subset of Lua is also Turing complete.  Two functions `gsub` and `match` are enough to implement anything.  So, any regular language can be implemented using Lua patterns.

Comment: OK, then prove it. Show how to use a *single pattern* (not a sequence of repeated calls to Lua functions. That's cheating) that is equivalent to a regular expression. A single Lua pattern that matches repeated sequences of the strings "Foo" and "Bar", but with no other characters between them. So "Foo", "BarFoo", "BarFooFooBarFoo" all match, but not "FoBaF".

Comment: @NicolBolas - Of course, it is impossible to implement using only one pattern.  Not everything could be implemented on Turing complete language by limiting program length to only one statement.  The OP title asks "Can Lua **patterns** represent any regular language?"  The answer is "Yes".